# Loop not gathering all values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, for-loop

I am trying to create 2 loops that work one after each other. I am basically trying to get all the fruits from the array. I have tried doing a for loop inside a for loop but that only gives me the first fruit from each object not every single fruit in the array.

```
var customers = [{
            "Name" : "John",
            "Items" :[
                {"Fruits" : "Apple"},{"Fruits" : "Orange"}]
            },{
                "Name" : "Sam",
            "Items" :[
                {"Fruits" : "Pear"},{"Fruits" : "Nuts"}]
            },{
                "Name" : "Eric",
            "Items" :[
                {"Fruits" : "Banana"},{"Fruits" : "Raisins"}]
            }];
 for(i=0; i<=customers.length; i++){
 for(a=0; a<=customers.length; a++){
     alert(customers[i]["Items"][a]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *second for-loop* should be `items` rather than `customers`

```
for(i=0; i < customers.length; i++) //notice that i < instead of i <=
{
   for(a=0; a < customers[i].Items.length; a++) //notice the change here
   {
     alert( customers[i].Items[a].Fruits ); // 
   }
}
```

A little more precise one would be using `reduce`

```
var allFruits = customers.reduce( ( a, b ) => a.concat( b.Items.map( s => s.Fruits ) ) , []);
```

Comment: Also should be `i <` and `a <` rather than the `i <=` and `a <=`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop has an incorrect length. Try this:

```
    var customers = [{
                "Name" : "John",
                "Items" :[{"Fruits" : "Apple"},{"Fruits" : "Orange"}]
            },{
                "Name" : "Sam",
                "Items" :[{"Fruits" : "Pear"},{"Fruits" : "Nuts"}]
            },{
                "Name" : "Eric",
                "Items" :[{"Fruits" : "Banana"},{"Fruits" : "Raisins"}]
            }];
 for(i=0; i<=customers.length; i++){
    for(a=0; a<=customers[i]["Items"].length; a++){
        alert(customers[i]["Items"][a]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue.

```js
var customers = [{
            "Name" : "John",
            "Items" :[
                {"Fruits" : "Apple"},{"Fruits" : "Orange"}]
            },{
                "Name" : "Sam",
            "Items" :[
                {"Fruits" : "Pear"},{"Fruits" : "Nuts"}]
            },{
                "Name" : "Eric",
            "Items" :[
                {"Fruits" : "Banana"},{"Fruits" : "Raisins"}]
            }];
 for(i=0; i<customers.length; i++){
 for(a=0; a<customers[i]["Items"].length; a++){
     console.log(customers[i]["Items"][a]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `concat` method in combination with `map` and `reduce` for a easy solution.

```
let fruits = [].concat(...customers.map(a => a.Items.map(b=>b.Fruits)));
```

```js
var customers = [{ "Name" : "John", "Items" :[ {"Fruits" : "Apple"},{"Fruits" : "Orange"}] },{ "Name" : "Sam", "Items" :[ {"Fruits" : "Pear"},{"Fruits" : "Nuts"}] },{ "Name" : "Eric", "Items" :[ {"Fruits" : "Banana"},{"Fruits" : "Raisins"}] }];

let fruits = [].concat(...customers.map(a => a.Items.map(b=>b.Fruits)));
console.log(fruits);
```

If you want to get all `unique` fruits, you can use `Set` from `ES6`.

```js
var customers = [{ "Name" : "John", "Items" :[ {"Fruits" : "Apple"},{"Fruits" : "Orange"}] },{ "Name" : "Sam", "Items" :[ {"Fruits" : "Pear"},{"Fruits" : "Nuts"}] },{ "Name" : "Eric", "Items" :[ {"Fruits" : "Banana"},{"Fruits" : "Raisins"}] }];
let fruits = [...new Set([].concat(...customers.map(a => a.Items.map(b=>b.Fruits))))];
console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: Since you are using ES6, you can try `[].concat(...customers.map(...))`